# SSL Certificate for Ubuntu machine running multiple docker containers and website

Tags: docker, apache, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an Ubuntu Machine with a Public IP, on it I am running 2 servers inside of docker containers  each one on it's own port and then aside from that I have a small website with some simple html+js.  The thing is I am making an iOS app that has to connect to said server to make a couple API requests but it fails because I don't have an SSL certificate.

My question is do I need an SSL certificate for each container, can I have 1 for the whole Ubuntu machine or what would be the way to go?

If I haven’t explained myself correctly let me know and I'll clarify whatever is needed.
Thanks!

I have come across installing a certificate for nginx or apache but I'm not sure how they work or if they are a valid solution to my problem.

Also, and maybe unrelated but just in case its relevant, the website is currently being run using the npm http-server package.